# Prove that if any open cover for $ K$ has a finite subcover, then $K$ is a compact set.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

Let $K$ be a subset of $\Bbb R. $ All  of the following statements are
equivalent in the sense that any one ofthem implies the two others:

(i)$ K$ is compact.

(ii) $ K$ is closed and bounded.

(iii) Any open cover for $ K$ has a finite subcover.

I was interested in the proof below:

Proof. The equivalence of (i) and (ii) is the content of Heine-Borel Theorem.  What
remains is to show that (iii) is equivalent to (i) and (ii). Let’s first assume (iii),
and prove that it implies (ii) (and thus (i) as well).
To show that $ K$  is bounded, we construct an open cover for $ K$ by defining
$O_{x}$ to be an open interval of radius $1$ around each point $x ∈ K.$ In the language
of neighborhoods, $O_x = V_1(x).$ The open cover $\{O_x : x ∈ K\}$ then must have
a finite subcover $\{O_{x_1} ,O_{x_2} ,... ,O_{x_n} \}.$  Because $K$ is contained in a finite union
of bounded sets, $K$ must itself be bounded.

The proof that $K$ is closed is more delicate, and we argue it by contradiction.
Let $(y_n)$ be a Cauchy sequence contained in $K$ with $\lim y_n = y.$ To show that
$K$ is closed, we must demonstrate that $y ∈ K,$ so assume for contradiction that
this is not the case. If $y\notin K,$ then every $x ∈ K$ is some positive distance away
from $y.$  We now construct an open cover by taking $O_{x}$ to be an interval of radius
$\frac{|x−y|}{2}$ around each point $x$ in $K.$ Because we are assuming (iii), the resulting
open cover $\{O_{x} : x ∈ K\}$  must have a finite subcover $\{O_{x_1}, O_{x_2},... ,O_{x_n}\}.$ The
contradiction arises when we realize that,  this
finite subcover cannot contain all of the elements of the sequence $(y_n).$ To make
this explicit, set
$\epsilon_0 = \text{min }\{\frac{|x_i − y|}{2}: 1 ≤ i ≤ n\}.$

Because $(y_n) → y,$  we can certainly find a term  $y_N$ satisfying $|y_N −y| < \epsilon_0.$ But
such a $y_N$  must necessarily be excluded from each $O_{x_i}$ , meaning that
$y_N \notin \bigcup_{i=1}^n O_{x_i}.$ Thus our supposed subcover does not actually cover all of $K.$ This contradiction implies that $y ∈ K,$ and hence $K$ is closed and bounded.
The proof that (ii) implies (iii) is outlined as an  exercise.

---

However, I feel a little uncomfortable with the line:

> "Let $(y_n)$ be a Cauchy sequence contained in $K$ with $\lim y_n = y.$"

I know that such a sequence is entirely possible to be contained in $K.$ However, what if $K$ is  a finite set. Then shouldn't we consider the convergent sequence ( or Cauchy sequence) as a constant sequence ? This is taking note  of the fact that  no other information about  $K.$

Also, I am unable to understand,  the meaning of :

> Because we are assuming (iii), the resulting
> open cover $\{O_{x} : x ∈ K\}$  must have a finite subcover $\{O_{x_1}, O_{x_2},... ,O_{x_n}\}.$ The
> contradiction arises when we realize that,  this
> finite subcover cannot contain all of the elements of the sequence $(y_n).$ To make
> this explicit, set
> $\epsilon_0 = \text{min }\{\frac{|x_i − y|}{2}: 1 ≤ i ≤ n\}.$
>
> Because $(y_n) → y,$  we can certainly find a term  $y_N$ satisfying $|y_N −y| < \epsilon_0.$ But
> such a $y_N$  must necessarily be excluded from each $O_{x_i}$ , meaning that
> $y_N \notin \bigcup_{i=1}^n O_{x_i}.$ Thus our supposed subcover does not actually cover all of $K.$ This contradiction implies that $y ∈ K,$ and hence $K$ is closed and bounded.

Neither do I realize how does "  this
finite subcover cannot contain all of the elements of the sequence $(y_n).$" ? Nor do I get the explicit reason for this as given in the subsequent section. To be really specific, I don't know, what's happening in this section at all.

---

According to @krm2233 's answer, my understanding for the second part, is:

> We assume, that $B(a,b)$ denotes the $b$ neighborhood of $a,$ i.e $B(a,b)=\{x\in\Bbb R| x\in (a-b,a+b)\},$ and $d(a,b)$ is just the scalar distance between $a$ and $b$ in the real line.
>
> We make a claim that the inequality $d(y,z) \geq d(y,x_j)-d(z,x_j) = 2\delta_{x_j} - d(x_j,z) > \delta_{x_j}\geq \epsilon,$ is true.
> Indeed, this is true, as if, we consider the   three cases, i.e
> $z$ can be a $x_j$ or it may be in the $\delta {x_j}$ neighborhood of $x_j.$
>
> If the later is the case, then, there are again two subcases, i.e :
>
> $z$ might be in the left hand side of $x_j$ or,
>
> $z$ might be in the right hand side of $x_j.$
>
> If $z$ is on the left hand side of $x_j$ then, $d(y,z)=d(y,x_j)-d(z,x_j) = 2\delta_{x_j} - d(x_j,z) > \delta_{x_j}\geq \epsilon.$
>
> On the other hand, if $z$ is on the left hand side of $x_j$ then, $d(y,z)=d(y,x_j)+d(z,x_j)$ and hence, if $d(y,z)\geq d(y,x_j)-d(z,x_j)$ is true then, $d(y,z)=d(y,x_j)+d(z,x_j)\geq d(y,x_j)-d(z,x_j)$ is true and so, $d(z,x_j)\geq -d(z,x_j)\implies 2d(z,x_j)\geq 0\implies d(z,x_j)\geq 0$ is true, which is true as $d(z,x_j)$ is the distance b/w $z$ and $x_j$ and distance is always a positive quantity. So, $d(y,z)\geq d(y,x_j)-d(z,x_j)$ is true. So, $d(y,z)\geq d(y,x_j)-d(z,x_j)=2\delta_{x_j}-d(z,x_j)\geq \delta x_j\geq \epsilon.$
>
> Now, we are left to examine the case, when $z=x_j$ then, $d(y,z)=d(y,x_j)=\delta_{x_j}\geq \epsilon.$
>
> So, in all the cases, we have $d(y,z)\geq \epsilon$ whenever, $z\in \bigcup _{i=1}^n B(x_i, \delta x_i).$ As, $K\subset  \bigcup _{i=1}^n B(x_i, \delta x_i)$, so, if $k\in K$ then , it means $k\in   \bigcup _{i=1}^n B(x_i, \delta x_i)$ and hence, $k\geq \epsilon.$
>
> But as $(y_n)$ is a convergent sequence in $K$ ( that converges to $y$ ) so, $\exists n_0\in\Bbb N$ such that $|y_n-y|\lt \epsilon,\forall n\geq n_0.$ In particular,  $\exists y_N\in (y_n)\subset K$ such that $|y_N-y|=d(y,y_N)\lt \epsilon,$ a contradiction as $y_N\in K\subset \bigcup _{i=1}^n B(x_i, \delta x_i),$ and so, $d(y_N,y)\geq \epsilon.$
>
> Thus, $y\in K.$ This proves that iii implies ii.

@krm2233 in the answer, also provided me with a validation, if, which I understand correctly states that:

> If $K$ is a finite compact set, then any convergent (or a Cauchy )sequence say, $(y_n)$ in $K$ must be a constant sequence, then, the point of convergence, (i.e $\lim y_n=) y$ is in $K.$
>
> "Now, when we take the assumption that a convergent sequence say, $(y_n)$ has a point of covergence ,(better say, limit) $y$ such that $y\notin K$, then, $(y_n)$ is *indeed not at least a constant sequence.* " The validity of this particular statement, is trivially obvious. But in the answer, it's written that :
>
> "Indeed once you suppose $y\notin K$ but $y_n \to y$, then you can check that $(y_n)$ must take on infinitely many distinct values (it is basically the same argument as the one used in the proof)."
>
> My problem is where it's written that "then you can check that $(y_n)$ must take on infinitely many distinct values (it is basically the same argument as the one used in the proof)". The fact is true by intution, and seems too much obvious to me. Is this a suggestion that I should try to show this fact rigorously ? Also, what is meant by the part "it is basically the same argument as the one used in the proof" ? I don't get this and a further clarification should be helpful.

I recently posted the proof-explanation question above, and received an answer from a fellow user. However, I still have some doubts regarding the answer and would appreciate the community's assistance in validating my understanding of it.

To ensure clarity, I have updated my original post to include my interpretation of the user's answer. I have broken down the key points of the answer and provided my understanding of each point.

I kindly request fellow community members and specifically @krm2233 to review my understanding and provide their input. I am particularly interested in knowing if I have correctly grasped the concepts explained in the original answer of @krm2233. Any feedback or corrections would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you all for your time and support. I look forward to engaging in discussions and refining my understanding with your valuable input.

Comment: The statement in your title is the *definition* of compact, usually… so how do you define compact

Comment: @FShrike My definition of a compact set is : *A set $K$ is called a compact set if for every sequence in $K$ $\exists$ a convergent subsequence such that it converges to a point in $K.$ In other words, a set is compact, iff it is closed and bounded.* Is there any way to prove that "If $K$ is closed and bounded then for every open cover of $ K$ , there is a finite subcover(, and hence, $K$ is a compact set) ", as it seems to be the definition you are using ?

Comment: Your post will be clearer if you change your vocabulary to the standard one, i.e. replace everywhere "compact" with "[sequentially compact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequentially_compact_space)", and "every open cover of $K$ has a finite subcover" with "$K$ is compact". E.g. the title should be: "Prove that every compact subset of $\Bbb R$ is sequentially compact". But more appropriatly (since this is the point which bothers you)  "Prove that every compact subset of $\Bbb R$ is closed".  Note that you only need [countably compact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countably_compact_space).

Comment: At the beginning of the proof, you write " The equivalence of (i) and (ii) is the content of Heine-Borel Theorem." [With the standard definition of compactness this would be correct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Borel_theorem). Hence not with your personal definition (which is usually called sequential compactness).

Comment: @ThomasFinley: In your argument to establish the triangle inequality you break the argument into cases you describe as being when $z$ is to the left or right of $x_j$. I think what you mean to say is when $z$ is on the same side of $x_j$ as $y$ or the opposite side of $x_j$ (i.e. into two cases according as to whether $z-x_j$ and $y-x_j$ have the same or opposite signs). In fact the inequality $|x-z|\leq |x-y|+|y-z|$ follows from the inequality $|a+b|\leq |a|+|b|$ by setting $a=x-y,b=y-z$, and the inequality $|a+b|\leq |a|+|b|$ by symmetry reduces to the cases $a<0\leq b$ and $0\leq a,b$.

Answer (score 2):

In relation to your first concern, when showing $K$ is closed, the proof considers a Cauchy sequence in $K$ converging to $y \in \mathbb R$, and supposes that $y\notin K$. If $K$ is a finite set, then any sequence $(y_n)$ in $K$ which converges must be eventually constant, and so converge to a point in $K$. Indeed once you suppose $y\notin K$ but $y_n \to y$, then you can check that $(y_n)$ must take on infinitely many distinct values (it is basically the same argument as the one used in the proof).

For the final part, the proof uses the fact that if $\delta_x = |y-x|/2$ then $K \subseteq \bigcup_{x \in K} B(x,\delta_x)$ is an open cover, so if $K$ satisfies (iii) it has a finite subcover, and this means that there are finitely many points $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ in $K$ with $K\subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^n B(x_i,\delta_{x_i})$. But if $\epsilon = \min\{\delta_{x_i}: 1\leq i\leq n\}$, then any $z \in K\subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^n B(x_i,\delta_{x_i})$ must have $|z-y|>\epsilon$, since for any such $z$ there is some $j\in \{1,\ldots,n\}$ with $z \in B(x_j,\delta_{x_j})$ and so
$$
|y-z| \geq |y-x_j|-|x_j-z| = 2\delta_{x_j} - |x_j-z| > \delta_{x_j}\geq \epsilon.
$$
(Here we are using the "triangle inequality" which states that $|x-z|\leq |x-y|+|y-z|$. For the real numbers it is easy to check, but the name comes from the case of $\mathbb R^2$ with the normal Euclidean distance $d((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)) = \sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2}$, where it is equivalent to the statement that the length of one side of a triangle is bounded above by the sum of the lengths of the other two sides.)

But the sequence $(y_n)$ tends to $y$, so $|y_n-y|\to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, and all the $y_n$s lie in $K$, hence we have a contradiction.

Notice that a variation of this argument shows that if $y$ is a limit point of a set $K$ and $y \notin K$ then $K$ must be infinite: indeed if $K$ is finite, say K ={$k_1,\ldots,k_m$} then for any $y \notin K$ if we set $\delta = \min\{|k_i-y|: 1\leq i\leq m\}$, we have $(y-\delta,y+\delta)\cap K= \emptyset$, so that $K^c$ is open, that is $K$ is closed.

The proof you are using is a little circuitous really. If you know that $K$ satisfies (iii) you can show it is closed and bounded as follows: (we will use the notation $B(x,r)$ for the "open ball of radius r centred at x", which in the case when one is working with points on the real line is just $(x-r,x+r)$, an open interval centred at $a$.

1. To see it is bounded, note that $K \subseteq \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty (-n,n)= \mathbb R$, and so $\mathcal U = \{U_n = (-n,n): n \in \mathbb N\}$ is an open cover of $K$, and so $K$ lies in the union of finitely many of the $U_n$s. But the $U_n$s are nested (that is, $U_n\subseteq U_{n+1}$ for each $n \geq 1$) and so a finite union of $U_n$s is equal to the largest of them, hence there is some $N>0$ with $K\subseteq (-N,N)$ and hence $K$ is bounded.
2. To see $K$ is closed, suppose that $y\notin K$. If $U_n = \{x \in \mathbb R: |x-y|>1/n\}$ we have $K\subseteq \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty U_n=\mathbb R \backslash\{y\}$, an open cover of $K$. Thus as $K$ satisfies (iii), it lies in a finite union of the $U_n$s, but as these are again nested it follows that there is some $N$ with $K\subseteq U_N$. Now as $K \subseteq \{x \in \mathbb R: |x-y|>1/N\}$, it follows that $B(y,1/N)\cap K = \emptyset$, that is $B(y,1/N)\subseteq \mathbb R\backslash K$. Thus $\mathbb R\backslash K$ is open, and hence $K$ is closed as required.

Comment: (+1) on the direct proof of (iii) $\implies$ (ii). Minor detail:  Where you write "$K$ is compact" you should write "condition (iii)", since (iii) is not the OP's definition of compact. (The excerpt appears to be from Abbott, which uses sequential compactness as the definition of compact.)

Comment: Thanks -- I think because the quoted text says that (i) and (ii) are equivalent by the Heine-Borel theorem, I read compact to mean "open-cover" compact, because I think that is what Heine and Borel did. The fact that sequential compactness is equivalent to closed and bounded for subsets of $\mathbb R$ was, I think, due to Bolzano and Weierstrass?

Comment: @km2233 Can you please explain the meaning of the symbol $B(x,\delta_x)$ ? It appears you used it here in many ways. I never encountered this symbol /notation earlier, so it will be really very helpful if you consider specifying the meaning.

Comment: @krm2233 If I assume $B(a,b)$ refers to the $b$ neighborhood of $a,$ (is it ?) then also, I am having a hard time understanding the inequality "$d(z,y)>\epsilon$, since there is some $j\in \{1,\ldots,n\}$ with $z \in B(x_j,\delta_{x_j})$ and so 
$$
d(y,z) \geq d(y,x_j)-d(z,x_j) = 2\delta_{x_j} - d(x_j,z) > \delta_{x_j}\geq \epsilon.
$$" ? I don't understand,  why is $$
d(y,z) \geq d(y,x_j)-d(z,x_j) = 2\delta_{x_j} - d(x_j,z) > \delta_{x_j}\geq \epsilon.
$$ true?

Comment: @krm2233 Please take a look at my now edited post, and oblige me by providing me with your valuable comments/suggestions/inputs. Thank you!

Comment: I've edited my answer to explain the notation $B(x,r)$ -- it is exactly what you thought it was! In the inequality you ask about, the first inequality follows from the "triangle inequality" -- a basic property of functions we view as giving a "distance" now described in the answer. The equality $|y-x_j|-|x_j-z| = 2\delta_{x_j} - |x_j-z|$ follows from the definition of $\delta_{x_j}$, and then the next inequality follows from the fact that, as  $z \in B(x_j,\delta_j)$, so $|z-x_j|<\delta_{x_j}$ and hence $2\delta_{x_j} - |x_j-z| = \delta_{x_j} + (\delta_{x_j}-|x_j-z|>\delta_{x_j}$

Comment: I have also added a short comment about the fact that if a set C has a limit point which is not contained in C then C is infinite. This is just a slightly complicated way of saying that any finite set is closed, and that is straight-forward to prove.

Comment: @krm2233 Thanks! Can you please comme nt on my *newly edited post* ? (Just to ensure, we are on the same page.)