# Prove that if $K$ is a closed and bounded subset of $\Bbb R$ then every open cover of $K$ has a finite subcover

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

Let $K$ be a subset of $\Bbb R. $ All  of the following statements are
equivalent in the sense that any one ofthem implies the two others:

(i)$ K$ is compact.

(ii) $ K$ is closed and bounded.

(iii) Any open cover for $ K$ has a finite subcover.

I was interested in the proof of $ii\implies iii.$ The proof was outlined as an excercise in the way mentioned below:

(*Note: The definition being used in this context is -"A set $K$ is compact iff for every sequence in $K$ there exists a convergent subsequence in $K$ which converges at a point in $K$."*)

Assume $K$ satisfies $(i)$ and $(ii),$ and let $\{O_λ : λ ∈ Λ\}$ be an open cover for $K.$ For contradiction, let’s assume that no finite subcover exists. Let $I_0$ be a closed interval containing $K,$ and bisect $I_0$ into two closed intervals $A_1$ and $B_1.$

(a) Why must either $A_1 ∩ K$ or $B_1 ∩ K$ (or both) have no finite subcover consisting of sets from $\{O_λ : λ ∈ Λ\}.$

(b) Show that there exists a nested sequence of closed intervals $I_0 ⊇ I_1 ⊇ I_2 ⊇ ···$ with the property that, for each $n,$ $I_n ∩ K$ cannot be finitely covered and $\lim |I_n| = 0.$

(c) Show that there exists an $x ∈ K $ such that $x ∈ I_n$ for all $n.$

(d) Because $x ∈ K,$ there must exist an open set $O_{λ_0}$ from the original collection that contains $x$ as an element. Argue that there must be an $n_0$ large enough to guarantee that $I_{n_0} ⊆ O_{λ_0}.$ Explain why this furnishes us with the
desired contradiction.

---

I attempted to follow this outline as follows, and prove the implication required in a rigorous manner :

Assume $K$ satisfies $(i)$ and $(ii),$ and let ${O_λ : λ ∈ Λ}$ be an open cover for $K.$ For contradiction, let’s assume that no finite subcover exists. Let $I_0$ be a closed interval containing $K,$ and bisect $I_0$ into two closed intervals $A_1$ and $B_1.$

Now, we claim that both $A_1 ∩ K$ and $B_1 ∩ K$ have no finite subcover each, consisting of sets from ${O_λ : λ ∈ Λ},$ at the same time.

Assuming that if possible, both $A_1 ∩ K$ and $B_1 ∩ K$ have finite subcover each, consisting of sets from ${O_λ : λ ∈ Λ}.$ Now, as $A_1\cup B_1=I_0$, this means $(A_1\cap K)\cup (B_1\cap K)=K\cap (A_1\cup B_1)=K\cap I_0=K$ has a finite subcover, a contradiction. So our claim holds.

Next, we claim that (from (b)) that there exists a nested sequence of closed intervals $I_0 ⊇ I_1 ⊇
 I_2 ⊇ ···$ with the property that, for each $n,$ $I_n ∩ K$ cannot be finitely covered
and $\lim |I_n| = 0.$

Now, we define for a closed interval $J=[a,b]$, $|J|=b-a\gt 0.$

From the previous claim we consider, $I_1=A$ and $I_1'=B$. Now, both $I_1,I_1'$ can't be finitely covered with $O_c,$ for then it would imply $K$ can be finitely covered with $O_c$. We choose an arbitrary set from $I_1,I_1'$ such that the chosen set, cannot be finitely covered with $O_c.$ WLOG, assuming $I_1$ is such a set. We then again bisect $I_1$ into $I_2$ and $I_2'$ and by the analogous argument as above, we may say, either $I_2$ or $I_2'$ cannot be covered with $O_c.$ We then choose such a set out of $I_2$ and $I_2'$ and repeat the process.

We hence, get a sequence of $I_n,n\in\Bbb N$ such that $I_0 ⊇ I_1 ⊇ I_2 ⊇ ···$ with $\lim |I_n| = 0,$ since from definition of $|I_n|$ we have $|I_n|=\frac{b-a}{2^n}$, where, $I_0=[a,b].$

---

But I am having some issues with this.

Firstly, for a set $A$ we generally denote the cardinality of $A$ as $|A|.$  But, as $I_0$ is a closed interval, and as it seems that $I_n,n\in \Bbb N,$ are also some nested closed intervals in $I_0$, and hence all the $I_n's$ are infinite sets so, the point, they make in the claim i.e $\lim |I_n| = 0,$ looks absurd. Hence, I defined $|I_n|$ appropriately.

Secondly, neither do I know how to divide $I_n$ into  a nested sequence of closed intervals $I_0 ⊇ I_1 ⊇
 I_2 ⊇ ···$ with the property that, for each $n,$ $I_n ∩ K$ cannot be finitely covered. To be precise, I could not prove the property, that "$I_n ∩ K$ cannot be finitely covered, for each $n\in \Bbb N.$"

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Sinve, I am stuck at this step, I can't proceed to do the remaining steps.

*I am also looking for a less circuitous proof of this implication, if it exists.*

Comment: (iii) is usually the *definition* of a compact set.

Comment: Didn’t you [just ask](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4707146) this?

Comment: @FShrike Ha ha, yeah I admit it might be confusing at first, but if you look closely there I asked $iii\implies ii$ but here, I asked $ii\implies iii.$

Comment: @MartinR The definition I am using is -"A set $K$ is compact iff for every sequence in $K$ there exists a convergent subsequence in $K$ which converges at a point in $K$"

Comment: @ThomasFinley: I would suggest to add that information to the question.

Comment: @MartinR Ok. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Your definition of compact is more generally known as *sequentially compact*. It is a theorem that metric spaces are compact iff. they are sequentially compact

Answer (score 1):

You solved your first issue correctly, i.e. here $|\cdot|$ does not denote the cardinality but the length of the interval.

As for the second issue, just apply recursively to $I_n\cap K$ the result of your first step: it is a *closed and bounded* subset of the closed interval $I_n$ (like $K$ was a closed and bounded subset of the closed interval $I_0$) and (by induction hypothesis) it is not finitely covered by $(O_\lambda)_{\lambda\in\Lambda}$ hence if you bissect $I_n$, one (at least) of the two closed subintervals, call it $I_{n+1},$ will be such that $K\cap I_{n+1}$ is not finitely covered either. But this seems to be what you already did, so I do not really understand your trouble.

Mine is elswhere: You want to prove $(ii)⟹(iii)$ but the exercise you quote assumes $(ii)$ **and $(i)$** to derive $(iii)$. It seems they want to use it for (c), saying "pick one $x_n$ in each $I_n\cap K,$ then by $(i)$ the sequence $(x_n)$ has a convergent subsequence, [...]" but this can be achieved much cheaply without $(i)$: since $\lim|I_n|\to0$ and $(I_n)$ is a nested sequence, the sequence $(x_n)$ itself converges because it is Cauchy.

Incidentally:

- Your post will be clearer *from the beginning* if, as [commented in the previous one](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4707146/timeline#comment_9966787), you adopt the standard vocabulary, i.e. replace everywhere "compact" with "[sequentially compact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequentially_compact_space)" (especially in (i)), and "every open cover of K has a finite subcover" with "K is [compact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_space#Open_cover_definition)" (especially in (iii)).
- This $(ii)\implies(iii)$ is the non-easy part of Heine-Borel theorem $(ii)\iff(iii).$ Your proof is standard and is essentially the same as [the proof on Wikipedia's page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Borel_theorem#Proof) of "If a set is closed and bounded, then it is compact" (except that there, they generalize to $\Bbb R^n$).